# Configurar cadena de conexión en proyecto de librería en .net 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Buen día a todos, estoy iniciando en .net 6 vengo de .net framework y estoy tratando de configurar la cadena de conexión de mi entity (uso databse first).

Mi solución esta estructurada de la siguiente forma (3 proyectos):

-Acceso a Datos

- Carpeta con entity

  - Context.cs

-Aplicación (Tiene la lógica y tiene referencia a acceso a datos)

-Proyecto web asp mvc (Referencia  proyecto aplicación)

- appsettings.json (tiene la cadena de conexión que se quiere usar)

Cuando cree el entity se genero la configuración del context de la siguiente manera:

```
  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.; Database=xxxxx; Trusted_Connection=True;");
            }
        }
```

agregue la siguiente configuración en el proyecto web (Program.cs) para que tome la cadena de conexión que esta en el archivo appsettings.json

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MiDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

pero esta tomando la cadena de conexión que esta en el archivo context en el proyecto de acceso a datos.

Como puedo hacer para que tome la cadena de conexión que configuro en el proyecto web asp mvc?

Comment: cuando vas a usar la base de datos, lo haces por medio de una nueva instancia de MiDBContext, tal como var db = new MiDBContext(); ?? el servicio .AddDbContext que estas agregando en Program funciona con dependency injection y como tal deberias de acceder a el por ese medio, una interfaz.

Comment: Si cuando uso la base de datos lo hago de la forma en que comentas. Al agregar la configuracion de la cadena de conexion con AddDbContext no funciona, sigue tomando la cadena de conexion que se especifica en el metodo OnConfiguring.

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, con esto me di una idea: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/43389530/how-to-get-connection-string-in-class-library-project  , 1.- En el proyecto de acceso a datos le paso la cadena de conexion se la paso al context por el contructor, 2.- En el proyecto de aplicacion creo una clase que funciona como singleton para pasarle la cadena de conexion cuando creo el Context, 3.- En el proyecto MVC asigno el valor de la cadena de conexion (que esta en la clase singleton) en el archivo program: ConnectionString.Value = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

Comment: Bueno en realidad para lo que lo agregas como servicio en Program.cs es para poderlo usar con dependency injection, mediante el constructor de tu clase, por ejemplo en tu controlador en su constructor, HomeController(MiDContext dbContext) y asi con cualquier clase que se injecte tambien. Pero si te funciono, me parece interesante como se solucion la verdad.